# When *is* classification accuracy the right measure of performance

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-evaluation, accuracy, scoring-rules

Plenty has been discussed on Cross Validated about the drawbacks of classification accuracy when it comes to evaluating [classification](/questions/tagged/classification) models. One good answer is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/247274), for instance.

Under what conditions *would* classification accuracy be the correct performance measure?

Two interesting examples can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/538524/247274) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/251654/247274). Can the logic there be fleshed out?